# How to use let with multiple params in RSpec expectation?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

```
  describe 'Spec' do
    let( :qux    ){ double 'qux' }
    let( :params ){ :foo, :bar, :baz }

    specify 'success' do
      qux.use :foo, :bar, :baz

      expect( qux ).to have_received( :use ).with params
```

This generates a syntax error because `:foo, :bar, :baz` is not valid Ruby.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Can't you put :foo, :bar, :baz in an array?

Comment: No, it doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the params in an array and use a splat if you want to do something like that. Also, since you're mocking `qux` you're going to have to stub out the `use` method:

```
RSpec.describe 'Spec' do
    let( :qux    ){ double 'qux' }
    let( :params ){ [:foo, :bar, :baz] }

    specify 'success' do
      qux.stub(:use)
      qux.use :foo, :bar, :baz
      expect( qux ).to have_received( :use ).with *params
    end
end
```

Comment: This works. It seems weird to create the array and then use an operator to remove it...

Answer (score 1):

`let(:var) { .. }` is easy to misinterpret, but it's actually pretty simple. You are evaluating a Ruby block, and whatever is returned from the let Ruby block gets assigned to :var.

With that in mind, you need to return an *actual* Ruby object from the let block.

Try this:

```
let(:params) do
  [:foo, :bar, :baz]
end
```

Comment: This is helpful. Unfortunately, an array is different from the 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

In [Rspec 3.0 or greater](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-1/docs/basics/expecting-messages), you must need to write it as

```
require 'rspec'

RSpec.describe 'Spec' do
  let( :qux    ) { double 'qux' }
  let( :params ) { [:foo, :bar, :baz] }

  it 'success' do
    expect(qux).to receive(:use).with(*params)
    qux.use(*params)
  end
end
```

And when I'll run this test :-

```
Arup-iMac:arup_ruby$ rspec spec/test_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.04997 seconds (files took 0.0904 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```